# C compiler cannot create executables whilst creating backport in Debian

Tags: debian, gcc, compiler, backports

I am trying to create a gcc-defaults-1.133 backport for my Debian Wheezy installation from Sid/Jessie. As this requires dpkg-dev greater than version 1.17.11 I assume I need a backport of this too.

So I grab the dsc and go into my dpkg-1.17.21~bpo70 folder. I add a few more dependencies then the following:

```
$ dch --local ~bpo70+ --distribution wheezy-backports "rebuild for wheezy backports"
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

The fakeroot command returns with:

```
dh_testdir
install -d build-tree
cd build-tree && ../configure --build=i486-linux-gnu --with-selinux --disable-silent-rules \
        CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers" CPPFLAGS="-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers" FCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong" FFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong" GCJFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,relro" OBJCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" OBJCXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security"  \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --mandir=\${datadir}/man \
        --infodir=\${datadir}/info \
        --sysconfdir=/etc \
        --sbindir=/sbin \
        --localstatedir=/var \
        --with-zlib \
        --with-liblzma \
        --with-bz2
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/rutherford/python3.4-3.4.1/gcc-defaults-1.133/dpkg-1.17.21~bpo70+2/build-tree':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [build-tree/config.status] Error 77
```

The config.log shows the following:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by dpkg configure 1.17.21, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --build=i486-linux-gnu --with-selinux --disable-silent-rules CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-pro
tector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-i
nitializers CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=form
at-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers FCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-
protector-strong FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong GCJFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong LDFLAG
S=-Wl,-z,relro OBJCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security OBJCXXFLAGS=-
g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security --prefix=/usr --mandir=${datadir}/man -
-infodir=${datadir}/info --sysconfdir=/etc --sbindir=/sbin --localstatedir=/var --with-zlib --with-libl
zma --with-bz2

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = myhost
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.2.0-4-686-pae
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/rutherford/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2883: checking for gcc
configure:2899: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2910: result: gcc
configure:3139: checking for C compiler version
configure:3148: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3159: $? = 0
configure:3148: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share
/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffi
x=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-incl
uded-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --ena
ble-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --en
able-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --with-arch-32=i586 --with
-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linu
x-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 
configure:3159: $? = 0
configure:3148: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3159: $? = 4
configure:3148: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3159: $? = 4
configure:3179: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3201: gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno
-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'
configure:3205: $? = 1
configure:3243: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "dpkg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "dpkg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.17.21"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "dpkg 1.17.21"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "debian-dpkg@lists.debian.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3248: error: in `/home/rutherford/python3.4-3.4.1/gcc-defaults-1.133/dpkg-1.17.21~bpo70+2/bui
ld-tree':
configure:3250: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_BZ2_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_BZ2_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra 
-Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CURSES_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_CURSES_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextr
a -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers'
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-Wl,-z,relro
ac_cv_env_LIBLZMA_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBLZMA_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PERL_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PERL_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PERL_set=
ac_cv_env_PERL_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_SELINUX_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_SELINUX_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_SSD_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_SSD_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_TAR_set=
ac_cv_env_TAR_value=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=i486-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR=''
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_V=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AUTOMAKE=''
AWK=''
BUILD_DSELECT_FALSE=''
BUILD_DSELECT_TRUE=''
BUILD_POD_DOC_FALSE=''
BUILD_POD_DOC_TRUE=''
BUILD_SHARED_FALSE=''
BUILD_SHARED_TRUE=''
BUILD_START_STOP_DAEMON_FALSE=''
BUILD_START_STOP_DAEMON_TRUE=''
BUILD_UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES_FALSE=''
BUILD_UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES_TRUE=''
BZ2_LIBS=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-para
meter -Wno-missing-field-initializers'
COVERAGE_ENABLED_FALSE=''
COVERAGE_ENABLED_TRUE=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
CURSES_LIBS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-pa
rameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers'
CYGPATH_W=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DOXYGEN=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GCOV=''
GETTEXT_MACRO_VERSION=''
GMSGFMT=''
GMSGFMT_015=''
GREP=''
HAVE_ALPHASORT_FALSE=''
HAVE_ALPHASORT_TRUE=''
HAVE_ASPRINTF_FALSE=''
HAVE_ASPRINTF_TRUE=''
HAVE_C99_SNPRINTF_FALSE=''
HAVE_C99_SNPRINTF_TRUE=''
HAVE_DOT=''
HAVE_GETOPT_FALSE=''
HAVE_GETOPT_LONG_FALSE=''
HAVE_GETOPT_LONG_TRUE=''
HAVE_GETOPT_TRUE=''
HAVE_LINKER_VERSION_SCRIPT_FALSE=''
HAVE_LINKER_VERSION_SCRIPT_TRUE=''
HAVE_OBSTACK_FREE_FALSE=''
HAVE_OBSTACK_FREE_TRUE=''
HAVE_SCANDIR_FALSE=''
HAVE_SCANDIR_TRUE=''
HAVE_SETEXECFILECON_FALSE=''
HAVE_SETEXECFILECON_TRUE=''
HAVE_STRERROR_FALSE=''
HAVE_STRERROR_TRUE=''
HAVE_STRNDUP_FALSE=''
HAVE_STRNDUP_TRUE=''
HAVE_STRNLEN_FALSE=''
HAVE_STRNLEN_TRUE=''
HAVE_STRSIGNAL_FALSE=''
HAVE_STRSIGNAL_TRUE=''
HAVE_SYS_ERRLIST_FALSE=''
HAVE_SYS_ERRLIST_TRUE=''
HAVE_UNSETENV_FALSE=''
HAVE_UNSETENV_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM=''
INTLLIBS=''
INTL_MACOSX_LIBS=''
LCOV=''
LCOV_GENHTML=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-Wl,-z,relro'
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBICONV=''
LIBINTL=''
LIBLZMA_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBICONV=''
LTLIBINTL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P=''
MSGFMT=''
MSGFMT_015=''
MSGMERGE=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='debian-dpkg@lists.debian.org'
PACKAGE_COPYRIGHT_HOLDER='Dpkg Developers'
PACKAGE_NAME='dpkg'
PACKAGE_STRING='dpkg 1.17.21'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='dpkg'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.17.21'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PERL_COVER=''
PERL_COVERAGE=''
PERL_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PO4A=''
POD2MAN=''
POSUB=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SELINUX_LIBS=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SSD_LIBS=''
STRIP=''
TAR=''
USE_NLS=''
USE_PO4A=''
USE_UNICODE=''
VERSION=''
WITH_SELINUX_FALSE=''
WITH_SELINUX_TRUE=''
XGETTEXT=''
XGETTEXT_015=''
XGETTEXT_EXTRA_OPTIONS=''
ZLIB_LIBS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
admindir=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot=''
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar=''
am__untar=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i486-linux-gnu'
build_alias='i486-linux-gnu'
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datadir}/info'
install_sh=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='/var'
logdir=''
mandir='${datadir}/man'
mkdir_p=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgconfdir=''
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "dpkg"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "dpkg"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.17.21"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "dpkg 1.17.21"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "debian-dpkg@lists.debian.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

What's wrong with my distribution's c compiler and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The package you're backporting is assuming GCC 4.9+ by adding `-fstack-protector-strong` to the command line. Your version of GCC (4.7.2) does not support this flag.

I'm not sure how `configure` is being called in this case, but the fix is to remove this flag from the script that calls it. (I assume you didn't actually type that huge command at the top of your `config.log` file by hand.)

There are [older flags](https://fedorahosted.org/fesco/ticket/1128) that do similar things, if you feel uncomfortable completely removing this flag.